# Display specific li tags using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have three php page, header.php where i put my ul tags and i have two hidden li tags on it(every pages is included my header.php), when i log in in my login.php, if login successful, my page will directly to the profile.php, and i want to show the two hidden li tags in my header.php. The problem is i don't know the exact syntax to show my li tags.
my header.php:

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav " > <!--navbar-nav-->

        <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">About us</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="about-us.php">The story</a></li>
                      <li><a href="culture.php">culture & services</a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="enabling-the-idea-in-a-space.php">Projects</a></li>
        <li class="hide"><a href="tender.php" >Tender</a></li>
        <li><a href="news.php">News</a></li>
        <!-- <li><a href="career.php">Career</a></li> -->
        <li><a href="contact-us.php">Contact us</a></li>    
        <li class="hide" name="profile" id="profile"><a href="Profile.php"  >Profile</a></li>

    </ul>
```

this is my code for showing the li tags in login.php:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM [Emkaandb].[dbo].[tbl_clientslogin] WHERE email='{$email}' AND password='{$password}'";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);

    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)){
        $username = $row['email'];
        $pass = $row['password'];
        $name = $row['name'];

    }
    if(($email != $username) && ($password != $pass)){
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                alert("Invalid Username/Password!"); 
                window.location.href = "home.php";
            </script>';         
        die();
    }else{
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                alert("WELCOME");
                window.location.href = "Profile.php";
            </script>';

        echo "<td><form action=Profile.php method=post>
                <input name=emailL type=text id=emailL value='".$row['email']."'>
            </form></td>";

        die();
    }
```

Comment: where is your header.php codes ?

Comment: above the login.php ivan

Comment: where di you check for user loged in or not ? where your login check codes.

Comment: the echo above is inside in my user login, my user logged in is working well, only for showing the li tags in my header.

Comment: I add an answer please check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**for login page**

```
<?php
    session_start();


    include 'connection.php';

    $email = $_POST['user'];
    $password = $_POST['pass'];
    $username = "";
    $pass = "";
    $name = "";

    //check if login form is filled
    if(empty($_POST['user']) || empty($_POST['pass'])){
        //header('Location: home.php');             when execute, ignore alert message
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                    alert("Username/Password Empty!"); 
                    window.location.href = "home.php";
                </script>';         
            die();
     }


    //search for user and password in the database
    $query = "SELECT * FROM [Emkaandb].[dbo].[tbl_clientslogin] WHERE email='{$email}' AND password='{$password}'";
    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);

        while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)){
            $username = $row['email'];
            $pass = $row['password'];
            $name = $row['name'];

        }
        if(($email != $username) && ($password != $pass)){
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                    alert("Invalid Username/Password!"); 
                    window.location.href = "home.php";
                </script>';
            die();
        }else{              
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                    alert("WELCOME");
                    window.location.href="Profile.php?chk=1&usr='.$username.'";
                </script>';
                /*echo "<td><form action=Profile.php method=get style=margin-top:-10%>
                        <input name=emailL type=text id=emailL value='".$row['email']."'>
                    </form></td>";*/
            die();
        }



?>
```

**for header.php**

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav " > <!--navbar-nav-->

        <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">About us</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="about-us.php">The story</a></li>
                      <li><a href="culture.php">culture & services</a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="enabling-the-idea-in-a-space.php">Projects</a></li>
        <?php if($check==1){
        echo '<li><a href="tender.php" >Tender</a></li>';
        ?>
        <li><a href="news.php">News</a></li>
        <!-- <li><a href="career.php">Career</a></li> -->
        <li><a href="contact-us.php">Contact us</a></li>    

        <?php if($check==1){
            echo '<li class="hide" name="profile" id="profile"><a href="Profile.php"  >Profile</a></li>';
        }
        ?>

    </ul>
```

**for Profile.php**

```
<h4 style="color:gray;"><b>Profile</b></h4>
            <h3><?php  echo $user; ?></h3>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="color: #5c5b5b;">
                    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#drawing">Drawings</a></li>
                    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#document">Documents</a></li>
                    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tender">Tender</a></li>
                    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#password">Change Password</a></li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: still not working man, can i ask you? where did you get the $login?

Comment: you must replace $login variable with your login variable. 
in this line I said if login is success print the <li> line
if user is not logged dont show the <li> line.
where is your login success variable ?

Comment: still not working man, if you can give me some sample codes, i'm very thankful. thank you anyway for your time man, well appreciated.

Comment: your welcome. but I don't use MSSQL and don't have examples for this. if you wanna I can send you example with mysql db.

Comment: i have additional concern man, i hope you don't mind, i want also to display the emailL in my login, into the profile php using <h3> tags

Comment: if you wanna send me this 3 php page to my mail for checking <ivanbarayev@hotmail.com>

Comment: its work or not :) ? if it work I will update my answer for other people